# Prove directly that a regular function on $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a constant map.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Exercise 3 of section 1.5.5 of Shavarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry I asks us to prove *directly* that regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are constant. I understand how one proves this statement for irreducible projective varieties using the theorem that the image of a projective variety under a regular map is closed. However I am not sure how to prove it directly, which I assume means without using that theorem. Does anyone have any useful hints or tips?

Comment: The regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are just the global sections of the structure sheaf. How have you defined the structure sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: I do not know what a structure sheaf is yet.

Comment: Ah apologies then, I've never read Shafarevich. How is "regular function" defined for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$, $\mathbb P^1$ can be obtained by gluing two open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ which are both isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1.$ So a regular function on $\mathbb P^1$ would mean a regular function $f_1$ on $U_1$ and a regular function $f_2$ on $U_2$ whose restriction to $U_1 \cap U_2$ is identical. Let's write $f_1 = p(x)$ and $f_2= q(y).$ Then we need $f_1$ and $f_2$ to satisfy $p(T) = q(T^{-1})$ in the ring $k[T, T^{-1}],$ where $k$ is the base field. This implies that $p$ and $q$ should both have degree $0$ as polynomials and in fact should agree as constants. The general case follows a similar idea.

Comment: Why do they need to satisfy $p(T) = q(T^{-1})$? I understand that $f_1$ and $f_2$ must agree on $U_1\cap U_2$, which for $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the set of points $(x:y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero, but I am not sure how we get $p(T) = q(T^{-1})$ from that? I'm guessing this has to do with homogeneous versus inhomogeneous coordinates but it's not clear to me.

Comment: Your guess is right. Let $(x :y)$ denote the homogeneous coordinates of P^1. Then on $U_1$ which is given by $y \ne 0$, we use the inhomogeneous coordinate and write $f_1= p(x/y)$ and on $U_2$ similarly $f_2= q(y/x)$ where $p $ and $q$ are polynomials from the ring $k[T].$ On $U_1 \cap U_2,$ $f_1$ and $f_2$ must agree but that can only happen if $p(T) =q(T^{-1})$..